# Can I access this checkbox using this?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

In my HTML file, I have the following list:

```
<ul >
       <li > <input type="checkbox" name="cbox" >do assignment 3</li>
        <li> <input type="checkbox" name="cbox" >study for test</li>
        <li > <input type="checkbox" name="cbox" >buy groceries</li>
        <li ><input type="checkbox" name="cbox">do more work</li> 
      </ul>
```

and I have the following function in my javascript file:

```
     $list.on('click', 'li', function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      ..some code
 }
```

I honestly don't feel like the rest of the code in the js file is very important, so I'll just ask what I'm confused about.

1. I notice that anytime I check on the checkbox, it also counts it as me having clicked on that list item, and so that function is called. Is there anyway to separate this so that checking or unchecking a checkbox does not automatically mean the same as clicking on the list item? I would think there probably isn't, because there the checkbox code is surrounded by `<li> </li>` tags. Does this mean that..it somehow becomes a part (or a child? Not sure about the terminology) of the li element? And if so, does that mean that I should be able to access the value of the checkbox using $this?

I tried doing $this.is(':checked') but that always seems to return false.

Comment: $this = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');

Comment: or please try to add `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: @Pekka Could you post that as an answer? Seems to me that stopping propagation is the correct way here. Perhaps explaining to OP what bubbling is would help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

> Description: Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

For more info check [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Comment: Wow, that was a simple fix. So I should be able to write another function like: $list.on('click', 'input[type=checkbox]', function()   and if I post event.stopPropogation(), I can make sure that my code follows instructions based only on whether the checkbox is checked or not, correct?

Comment: as the description says adding `event.stopPropagation()` will prevent your event from bubbling up meaning it will only be in the checkbox not the list. So i will say YES~

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.is()` within `click` handler to check if element clicked is `input type="checkbox"`

```
 $list.on("click", "li", function() {
    // if element clicked is not `input type="checkbox"` , do stuff
    if (!$(this).is(":checkbox")) {
      var $this = $(this);
      // ..some code
    }
 })
```